# Column and Row manipulation Python Pandas

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas, pandastream

This is my first program in Pandas on my own and I am trying to perform some csv manipulations by column and rows. I have a transition repository of multiple files. The transition repository keep adding file into it. I am trying to dynamically read the files and perform some operations and write to a master csv file in another folder.

Input

```
1. Folder_1: `Transition_Data`  


Test_1.csv, Test_2.csv

    Nos,Time,Count          Nos,Time,Count
    -------------------     ------------------
    2341,12:00:00,9865      1234,12:30:00,7865
    7352,12:00:00,8969      8435,12:30:00,7649

2. Folder2: Data_repository:Master_2.csv


    Nos,00:00:00
    ------------
    1234,1000
    8435,5243
    2341,563
    7352,345

3.Expected Output 

Nos,00:00:00,12:00:00,12:30:00
----------------------------------
1234,1000,0,6865
8435,5243,0,2406
2341,563,9302,0
7352,345,8624,0
```

Read `Nos` column from transition_data files and check where `Nos` is located in `Master_2.csv` The create a new column with `Time` as new header every time and subtract the `col[2]` of Transition_data files with `col[1]` of `Master_2.csv` fill the new value in newly created column if data gaps be filled with `0`. I did try with few examples around but I messed up.

Program Updates as explained below and now have problem routing the logic with file read and write

```
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import glob

path_1 = '/Transition_Data/'
path_2 = 'Data_repository/Master_2.csv'

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Nos=Nos, Time=Time, Count=Count))

pivot = pd.pivot_table(path_1, '/.*CSV, index='Nos', columns='Time', values='Count')

df_master = pd.DataFrame('Master_2.csv', {'Nos':, '00:00:00':}).set_index('Nos')

result = df_master.join(pivot, how='inner')

result[result.columns[1:]] = result[result.columns[1:]].sub(result[result.columns[0]], axis=0)

result.fillna(0)
```

I tried the above program and got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header='Count')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 420, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 218, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 502, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 610, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 972, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "parser.pyx", line 476, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:4538)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user is no longer a member of Stack Overflow. Any response or clarification to this question will not get response.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can see to do this is to join them all into a single DataFrame, sort the columns by time, then shift and subtract to get the delta:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path_1 = 'Transition_Data/'
path_2 = 'Data_repository/Master_2.csv'

# Read data, and combine "transition" data into 
# single joined data frame
master = pd.read_csv(path_2)
other_data = pd.concat([
        pd.read_csv(path_1 + f) for f in os.listdir(path_1)
    ])

# Index master data frame by Nos
master.set_index('Nos', inplace=True)

# Index transition data by Nos and Time
other_data.set_index(['Nos', 'Time'], inplace=True)

# Convert to series (to remove Count column heading)
# and unstack time to convert to columns
other_data = other_data['Count'].unstack('Time')

# Join the data sets on the Time axis
joined = pd.concat([master, other_data], axis=1)

# Sort the data sets by Time
joined = joined.sort_index(axis=1)

# Fill na values with data in previous period
joined = joined.fillna(method='pad',axis=1)

# Shift dataframe and subtract to get delta
delta = joined - joined.shift(axis=1).fillna(0)

print(delta)
```

This gives your desired output:

```
      00:00:00  12:00:00  12:30:00
Nos                               
1234      1000         0      6865
2341       563      9302         0
7352       345      8624         0
8435      5243         0      2406
```